# alternating between ascending and descending Sorting on Click reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code and I'm supposed to alternate between upper case and lower case on click. I already have the sorts available but I need to write another method so that it alternates. The code I've written doesn't alternate but only sorts ascending and then stops. We need to modify the (sorting) method.

**Code:**

```
ascending() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const copy = [...prevState.cars];
      copy.sort((a, b) => (a.year - b.year));
      return { cars: copy };
    });
}
    
descending() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const copy = [...prevState.cars];
      copy.sort((a, b) => (b.year - a.year));
      return { cars: copy };
    });
}

sorting() {
    let count=0;
    
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        this.ascending();
        count++;
    } else {
        this.descending();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Don't forget to set default value for "toggleSorting" while initializing 'state' begining of the cycle.

```
sorting = () => {
  const {
    toggleSorting,
  } = this.state;

  if(toggleSorting) {
    this.descending();
  } else {
    this.ascending();
  }
  this.setState({toggleSorting: !toggleSorting});
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by " Don't forget to set default value for "toggleSorting" while initializing 'state' begining of the cycle." Could you explain please. Also, I tried running the code you have given me but I get a blank screen, no errors show up but there seems to be some problem.

Comment: @MR.CODER1111, I mean you should add 'toggleSorting' property to your state if you are using class component. Eg. `constructor(props) {super(props); this.state = {toggleSorting: false};}`

Comment: @MR.CODER1111, can you create a sandbox? Need to see your whole code.

Comment: @MR.CODER1111, great to hear that :)